# Is this laptop compatible with 1 x 16 GM RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm going to upgrade a laptop [Asus N750JK](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N750JK/specifications/) and plug additional memory in it. My goal is to have maximum available capacity installed, but the specs of the laptop seem to contradict with the [specs of the CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/75027/Intel-Core-i5-4200H-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz) that it has installed (max 32 GB on Intel site vs max 16 GB on Asus). I previously already run into a situation when manufacturer specs are somewhat wrong, but not sure if the motherboard designed so that laptop can see memory more than 16 GB.

In order to figure it out i would like to buy 1 x 16 GB RAM chip, and mix it with existing 2 GB chip, and if the laptop can recognize both, i'll plug another 16 GB RAM, otherwise i can just leave a single 16 GB chip. The problem is that Asus specs also imply in context, that each slot can take up to 8 GB, so i will probably waste my money and time without any luck. Is there any way to check if this laptop supports at least one 16 GB RAM chip without buying it and having it in my hands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manufacturer will usually be right, and it can be limited by the memory slot itself or the motherboard.

And they clearly say:

> DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, 2 GB, **up to 16 G**, (8 GB x 2), 2x DIMM socket,
>   **DIMM Up to 8 G**

So the only way to really make sure is to buy and test...